# Using return value from another predicate to calculate value

Tags: prolog

I have the following code. All my other functions are working. I have already tested them. But when I add this particular code things begin to go kaboom. Even the functions remove-duplicates start behaving weirdly showing out of local stack. What might be the problem?

I am also getting this No permission to redefine imported_procedure `lists:append/3' sometimes.

```
common-unique-elements(L1,L2,Ans):-
    nested-to-simple(L1, L1_simple),
    nested-to-simple(L2, L2_simple),
    remove-duplicates(L1_simple, L1_F),
    remove-duplicates(L2_simple, L2_F),
    simple-intersection(L1_F, L2_F,F).
    append(F,[],Ans).
```

Comment: You are inadvertently calling predicates with primary functor `(-)/2`. Use underscores `_` to separate argument descriptions!

Comment: for example _L1, _L2?

Comment: No, for example `nested_to_simple`!

Comment: Why should that be an issue? Separating function name with '-' ?

Comment: Clauses of (-)/2 are not together in the source-file
  Earlier definition at  line 5
  Current predicate: inter/3
  Use :- discontiguous (-)/2. to suppress this message

What does this message mean?

Comment: As I said, you are inadvertently using `(-)/2` as the primary functor. In Prolog, `(-)/2` is an **infix operator**, so a term of the form `X-Y` is the same as `-(X, Y)`. In the code you posted, your goals look like this: `-(simple, intersection(L1_F, L2_F, F))`, which is almost certainly *not* what you intended to write. Instead, use `_` (underscore) to separate argument descriptions, as in `simple_intersection(L1_F, L2_F, F)`, which is the naming convention used in Prolog.  This may be helpful `?- write_canonical(nested-to-simple(L1, L1_simple)).`, yielding: `-(-(nested,to),simple(_,_))`.

Comment: I fixed that, but the code is still behaving weird. For example if i do common_unique_elements([a,b,c],[a,b,c],Ans), I get Ans = [a,b,c]. But when I do common_unique_elements([a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b]) or common_unique_elements([a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a]) it still gives true.

Comment: Please file a separate question for this completely unrelated and new issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are also two periods in the code posted above. `common_unique_elements/3` ends with `simple_intersection/3`. Then you have a definition of `append/3` with no body.